# How to add an Array of strings to a Where clause

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following method:-

```
public IQueryable<ComponentDefinition> GetProducts(string[] type)
        { return entities.ComponentDefinitions.Where(a => a.ComponentType.COMPONENTTYPENAME.ToLower() == type.ToLower());

        }
```

But i am not sure how i can add something such as, so the where will include the array of strings :-
 :-

```
public IQueryable<ComponentDefinition> GetProducts(string[] type)
            { return entities.ComponentDefinitions.Where(a => a.ComponentType.COMPONENTTYPENAME.ToLower() == type.ToLower().Any(type));

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement you're looking for is

```
return entities.ComponentDefinitions
               .Where(a => type.Contains(a.ComponentType.COMPONENTTYPENAME));
```

But what about the `ToLower()`? You probably don't need it. The query is translated to SQL, which means that the comparison of strings is carried out in the database. So the database collation determines whether the comparison is case sensitive or not. In most cases the default is not case sensitive.

If by any chance the collation is case sensitive, you must do

```
return entities.ComponentDefinitions
               .Where(a => type
                   .Contains(a.ComponentType.COMPONENTTYPENAME.ToLower()));
```

and make sure the `type` array only contains lower case strings.

Comment: One remark. The second option is less attractive because it won't use any indexes on `COMPONENTTYPENAME`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
public IQueryable<ComponentDefinition> GetProducts(string[] type)
            { return entities.ComponentDefinitions.Where(a => type.Contains(a.ComponentType.COMPONENTTYPENAME));}
```

If not, then take a look at joining the collections on the COMPONENTTYPENAME field. I find that linq queries are easier to understand than lambda expressions in this case

```
var result = from e in entities.ComponentDefifintion
             join x in type on type.COMPONTENTTYPENAME.ToLower() equals e.COMPONENTTYPENAME.ToLower()
             select x;
```